# How to make a material ui chips array scroll left and right using arrows?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make material ui Chips scroll left and right in a single line.

Here is a code sandbox I am working on.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-meitner-lud7q?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly...

What you want is basically a single line of material-ui chips with scrolling when the container size is not enough to show everything.

[Demo code: Chips + overflow auto + maxWidth + flexWrap nowrap](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-material-ui-chips-single-line-with-scroll-244xx?file=/src/App.js)

It is somewhat easy to achieve this...

We can add `overflow:auto` and `maxWidth:400px` to the chips container element.
Basically, this tells the browser to show the scroll if the content requires more than 400px of horizontal space (width).

And to make the chips flow horizontally we just add to the container `flexWrap: nowrap` to instruct the render to do not wrap elements.

Sources:
[Github: material-ui - docs/src/pages/components/chips/ChipsArray.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/chips/ChipsArray.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly check out [react-material-ui-caraousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel).

Just like:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel'


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    listStyle: "none",
    padding: theme.spacing(0.5),
    margin: 0,
    maxWidth: "1000px"
  },
  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5)
  }
}));

export default function ChipsArray() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [chipData, setChipData] = React.useState([
    { key: 0, label: "Angular" },
    { key: 1, label: "jQuery" },
    { key: 2, label: "Polymer" },
    { key: 3, label: "React" },
    { key: 4, label: "Php" },
    { key: 4, label: "Golang" },
    { key: 4, label: "More" }
  ]);

  const handleDelete = (chipToDelete) => () => {
    setChipData((chips) =>
      chips.filter((chip) => chip.key !== chipToDelete.key)
    );
  };

  return (
    <Paper component="ul" className={classes.root}>
      <Carousel
        autoPlay={false}
        interval={0}
        animation="slide"
        timeout={100}
      >
            {
                chipData.map( (item, i) => (
                  <li key={item.key}>
                    <Chip
                      label={item.label}
                      onDelete={handleDelete(item)}
                      className={classes.chip}
                    />
                  </li>
                ) )
            }
        </Carousel>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Comment: A couple of drawbacks in my opinion - one chip per slide makes it kind of ugly especially on a desktop page. Also dependency on another library just for a slide effect. I am sure this can be done using plain js/ material ui. There is actually a way to do this using just Tabs and Chips. Will post answer when I fix the bugs. Thanks for your answer.